# Predefine line break positions in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, string, uilabel, line-breaks

I am looking for a solution for predefining the positions within a word where a line break should occur if necessary. This is necessary especially for long german words
What i want is to define a String in a way like this: "Be-nach-rich-ti-gun-gen" where all the '-' chars mark positions within the string where a line break can occur if necessary. On a small device there will be different line breaks than on a large device. Only the necessary line breaks should be taken into account, all the others should be ignored. Also I don't want to see the '-' chars if no line break is necessary. 
Do you know any solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you looked at TextKit yet? NSParagraphStyle has the property 'hyphenationFactor' which controls at what point words become hyphenated. Doesn't address your requirement for predefined line breaks, but may be a good starting point. Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nsparagraphstyle/ and some good info on it: https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/getting-to-know-textkit/

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Indeed I did not know much about TextKit. Looks very promising. But unfortunately, I did not find a solution to my particular problem yet.